# FInding the longest path that is <= x (weighted, undirected graph)

Tags: algorithm, graph, path

I can't think of any algorithm that would find the longest path, that is smaller or equal to some x variable. With Dijkstra's algorithm I can easily get longest path, however I'm not sure if I can use it in my problem.

Comment: Do you mean a simple path (without loops)?

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm will give you the shortest path, not the longest one.

Finding the longest (simple) path is NP-Hard. Since your problem can be degenerated into the longest path problem (take x equal to the sum of all edge weights, which is an upper bound on the length of the longest path), it is also NP-Hard.

You could still use a tree search, but it is not likely to be tractable.

If you are considering non-simple paths (nodes can be traversed several times) then it is a different problem. A degenerate case is the knapsack problem, which is NP-Hard as well.

Comment: Agreed, it looks similar to a knapsack problem to me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DFS algorithm in order to found longest path. If you search you can found some useful articles, like [Depth First Search & Directed Acyclic Graphs](http://www.csd.uoc.gr/~hy583/reviewed_notes/dfs_dags.pdf).