# find biggest area in graph with cost less then m

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph

I'm trying to find an algorithm that will, given an undirectional graph with positive cost for each edge, the maximum number of nodes that can be connected with less than a total cost m. I already implemented a version of Prim’s Algorithm (order Nlog(N)) which I can easily adopt to find the maximum number of nodes given a start node. However this can give problems in the situation where this node would not be part of the optimal solution.

I can of course solve this by looping over every node but this makes the solution N^2*log(N) which seems a bit much. Does anybody know if there is a more optimal solution?

Comment: If your weights are integers, you can find an MST in O(m + n) time using the paper "Trans-dichotomous algorithms for minimum spanning trees and shortest paths".

Comment: While I can't currently access the whole text it looks like it's doing the part I already implemented? Using a dykstra-like/greedy algorithm to find the minimal spanning tree with a limited cost, however the problem I'm having is that this only works given a certain starting node but the ideal solution can be any given starting node.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a modified version of [the Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

```
best_vertex = None
max = 0
for v in graph.vertices:
    n = largest_area(graph, cost, v)
    if n > max:
        best_vertex = v
        max = n

def largest_area(graph, max_cost, vertex, edges=[]):
    # Base Case
    if max_cost <= 0:
        return edges

    # Iterate through all the neighbours and find the highest scoring path.
    max_vertices = 0
    for n in graph.adjacent(vertex):
        edge = graph.get_edge(n, vertex)
        if edge in edges: continue # We've already taken that route.
        num_vertices = largest_area(graph, max_cost - edge.weight, edges + [edge])
        if num_vertices > max_vertices:
            max_vertices = num_vertices

    return max_vertices
```

Comment: This must be a *very* modified version of knapsack if the OP has a working polynomial time solution.

Comment: Although, re-reading your question - this probably doesn't beat n^2log(n).

Comment: @mbeckish I don't understand why this wouldn't be considered a modified 0/1 Knapsack problem (which has a running time of O(n*W))?

Comment: Because the OP has a O(N^2logN) solution, which is ploynomial, not a pseudo-polynomial O(nW) solution.

Comment: I'm not saying that your solution isn't good for this problem - I'm just saying that there must be a significant difference between this problem and knapsack if there exists a polynomial solution.

Comment: @mbeckish if there is a solution for knapsack in polynomial time, then `P = NP` and OP should go and award his $1.000.000

Comment: @mbeckish Ah, I understand. I have to read about Prim's algorithm to know if I am convinced that it is successful.

Comment: True - maybe the Op's solution is invalid.

Comment: The difference is that the knapsack problem is "find different shapes that are less then m and fit them in the bag" where as my question doesn't involve different shapes as we are building a minimal spanning tree of the solution (which takes n*log(n) steps) and try this from every single source (which takes n steps so n*n*log(n)). So it's a different problem.

Comment: @Thijser I disagree entirely. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182476/finding-the-longest-path-that-is-x-weighted-undirected-graph The minimal spanning tree is not necessarily the correct path.

Comment: Also, I've edited a link in my post pointing to the longest path problem entry on Wikipedia.

Comment: @sdasdadas At the very least every possible solution is a minimal spanning tree of it's nodes. If it was not then we could find a solution that is less costly for the same nodes meaning that potentially I could add another node(if there is one we couldn't add but was close).

Comment: Fundamentally it's possible to use a greedy algorithm in order to find a graph that connects nodes with a total cost of less then m in n*log(n) steps (I have already done so) given a start node. So if I cycle over each start node I have n*n*log(n) steps. I already have this available, however I'm wondering if it can be done faster.

Comment: OP's solution is need not be optimal as it is not considering the global objective and is greedy.

Comment: @Thijser Ah, I think I see the difference. It's because your problem can branch the path at any point - whereas the longest path must always continue from the last edge (I think...).

Comment: Yes my path can branch at any point and need not continue from the last point.